# Команда профиль не считывает новые данные

Tags: mysql, disnake

```
import disnake
import sqlite3
import asyncio
from disnake.ext import commands

database = 'profiles.db'  # Имя файла базы данных

# Создание и подключение к базе данных
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
c = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы, если она не существует
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profiles (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    joined_at TEXT,
    roles TEXT,
    status TEXT
)''')

class Profile(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        # Запустить задачу для периодического считывания данных пользователя
        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.read_user_data())

    async def read_user_data(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            # Считывание данных пользователя
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                for member in guild.members:
                    user_data = self.get_profile(member.id)
                    if user_data is None:
                        user_data = self.update_profile(member)

            await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Подождать 60 секунд

    @commands.slash_command(description='Просмотреть свой профиль.')
    async def profile(self, ctx):
        # Получение данных пользователя из базы данных или их обновление, если данные уже существуют
        user_id = ctx.author.id
        user_data = self.get_profile(user_id)
        if user_data is None:
            user_data = self.update_profile(ctx.author)
        
        emb = disnake.Embed(
            title="Профиль пользователя",
            description=" ",
            color=disnake.Colour.purple(),
        )
        
        emb.add_field(name=" Имя", value=user_data[1], inline=True)
        emb.add_field(name=" Дата входа на сервер", value=f'{user_data[2]}', inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name=f' Роли [{len(user_data[3])}]', value=' '.join(user_data[3]), inline=False)
        
        t = disnake.Status[user_data[4]]
        if t == disnake.Status.online:
            d = " В сети."
        elif t == disnake.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪️ Не в сети."
        elif t == disnake.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен."
        elif t == disnake.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить."
        else:
            d = "Ошибка"    
        
        emb.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d, inline=False)
        emb.set_footer(text=f'Запросил: {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)

        await ctx.send(embed=emb, ephemeral=True)

    def get_profile(self, user_id):
        # Получение данных пользователя из базы данных
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
        user_data = c.fetchone()
        return user_data

    def update_profile(self, user):
        # Обновление данных пользователя в базе данных или добавление новых данных
        roles = [role.name for role in user.roles if role.name != "@everyone"]
        status = str(user.status)
        
        c.execute("REPLACE INTO profiles (user_id, name, joined_at, roles, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                  (user.id, user.name, user.joined_at.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"), ' '.join(roles), status))
        conn.commit()

        return (user.id, user.name, user.joined_at.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"), roles, status)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Profile(bot))
```

Проблема: не выводит новые даные о состоянии юзера(статус) и вместо role mention он выводит непронятно что(пример: НУжно вывести @Admin а он выводит A d m i n)